# ggplot showing weird numbers instead of labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

My `ggplot` in Rstudio is showing strange numbers instead of labels for all plots. Below is a code from an example graph from `ggplot`'s website. The data is being plotted fine. But, all the labels are showing up as four digits with a box around them. I've tried reinstalling `ggplot` but I'm still facing the same problem. I'm using version 3.3.2

```
# library
library(ggplot2)

# basic graph
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point()

# a data frame with all the annotation info
annotation <- data.frame(
  x = c(2,4.5),
  y = c(20,25),
  label = c("label 1", "label 2")
)

# Add text
p + geom_text(data=annotation, aes( x=x, y=y, label=label),                 , 
              color="orange", 
              size=7 , angle=45, fontface="bold" )

# Note: possible to shorten with annotate:
# p +
#  annotate("text", x = c(2,4.5), y = c(20,25), 
#           label = c("label 1", "label 2") , color="orange", 
#           size=7 , angle=45, fontface="bold")

# Right chart: using labels
p + geom_label(data=annotation, aes( x=x, y=y, label=label),                 , 
               color="orange", 
               size=7 , angle=45, fontface="bold" )
```

[Here is the output on my screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj8TH.png)

And the `sessionInfo()`

```
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/liblapack.so.3

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8      
 [8] LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] Seurat_3.1.5                ggplot2_3.3.2               monocle3_0.2.1              SingleCellExperiment_1.8.0  SummarizedExperiment_1.16.1 DelayedArray_0.12.2         BiocParallel_1.20.1        
 [8] matrixStats_0.56.0          GenomicRanges_1.38.0        GenomeInfoDb_1.22.0         IRanges_2.20.2              S4Vectors_0.24.3            Biobase_2.46.0              BiocGenerics_0.32.0        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tsne_0.1-3             nlme_3.1-144           bitops_1.0-6           RcppAnnoy_0.0.16       RColorBrewer_1.1-2     httr_1.4.1             sctransform_0.2.1      tools_3.6.3           
 [9] R6_2.4.1               irlba_2.3.3            KernSmooth_2.23-16     uwot_0.1.8             lazyeval_0.2.2         colorspace_1.4-1       npsurv_0.4-0.1         withr_2.2.0           
[17] tidyselect_1.0.0       gridExtra_2.3          compiler_3.6.3         plotly_4.9.2.1         labeling_0.3           scales_1.1.0           lmtest_0.9-37          ggridges_0.5.2        
[25] pbapply_1.4-2          rappdirs_0.3.1         stringr_1.4.0          digest_0.6.25          XVector_0.26.0         htmltools_0.4.0        pkgconfig_2.0.3        htmlwidgets_1.5.1     
[33] rlang_0.4.6            rstudioapi_0.11        farver_2.0.3           zoo_1.8-8              jsonlite_1.6.1         ica_1.0-2              dplyr_0.8.5            RCurl_1.98-1.2        
[41] magrittr_1.5           GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.2 patchwork_1.0.0        Matrix_1.2-18          Rcpp_1.0.4.6           munsell_0.5.0          ape_5.3                reticulate_1.15       
[49] viridis_0.5.1          lifecycle_0.2.0        stringi_1.4.6          MASS_7.3-51.5          zlibbioc_1.32.0        Rtsne_0.15             plyr_1.8.6             grid_3.6.3            
[57] listenv_0.8.0          ggrepel_0.8.2          crayon_1.3.4           lattice_0.20-40        cowplot_1.0.0          splines_3.6.3          pillar_1.4.4           igraph_1.2.5          
[65] future.apply_1.5.0     reshape2_1.4.4         codetools_0.2-16       leiden_0.3.3           glue_1.4.0             lsei_1.2-0.1           data.table_1.12.8      png_0.1-7             
[73] vctrs_0.2.4            tidyr_1.0.3            gtable_0.3.0           RANN_2.6.1             purrr_0.3.4            future_1.17.0          assertthat_0.2.1       rsvd_1.0.3            
[81] survival_3.1-8         viridisLite_0.3.0      tibble_3.0.1           cluster_2.1.0          globals_0.12.5         fitdistrplus_1.0-14    ellipsis_0.3.0         ROCR_1.0-11
```

Comment: It works well to me. Maybe you can add your `sessionInfo()` to help

Comment: Also works fine for me. Looks like you don't have the correct fonts installed for some reason. What happens if you remove the ``fontface="bold"`` argument?

Comment: I'm getting the same result after removing `fontface="bold"`

Comment: Works fine for me as well. Make sure you try in a fresh R-session

Comment: What is the ouptut of `conflicts(,TRUE)`?

Comment: You may need to update RStudio version.